# Converting a string from snake case to camel case in Java

Tags: java, string

How can I convert snake case to camel case in Java?

Input: "input_in_snake_case"

Output: "InputInSnakeCase"

Comment: That other question is SO not a duplicate of this one. (Although some of the answers are pretty similar :) )

Comment: This question should be reopened, as it clearly states its use case being different from the marked duplicate.

Comment: We have at least: UPPERCASE, lowercase, camelCase, PascalCase, snake_case, SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE, hyphen-case, dot.case.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) supports this through its [CaseFormat](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/base/CaseFormat.java) class

```
import com.google.common.base.CaseFormat;


public class StackOverflow25680258 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(CaseFormat.UPPER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL, "input_in_snake_case")); 
    }

}
```

Output

```
InputInSnakeCase
```

Comment: I have the same issue. But if word is helloFunnyWORLD, result should be hello-funny-world. Guava solution is not suitable for me.

Comment: Just out of curiosity why is the class name `StackOverflow25680258`? Do you have some sort of macro?

Comment: @SureshS: the name of the method is given by the id of this question - see browser link :)

Comment: @Adam Is it possible to output: "inputInSnakeCase" ? I mean with first letter in lower case. (using guava not manually lower first letter)

Comment: @Lucke Yes - use CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL instead of CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL

Answer (score 0):

A java solution without dependencies assuming the input is actually snake case.

```java
  public static String makeCamelCase(final String snakeCase) {
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var lastChar = snakeCase.charAt(0);
    sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(lastChar));
    for (int i =1; i < snakeCase.length(); i++) {
      var c = snakeCase.charAt(i);
      sb.append(c);
      if (lastChar == '_') {
        sb.delete(sb.length()-2, sb.length());
        sb.append("_" + Character.toUpperCase(c));
      }
      lastChar = c;
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache Commons Text `toCamelCase` method:

```
import org.apache.commons.text.CaseUtils;

...

String snakeCaseText = "make_it_camel_case";
System.out.println(CaseUtils.toCamelCase(snakeCaseText, false, '_'));
```

Output of the code above would be "makeItCamelCase".

Method documentation can be found on:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/CaseUtils.html#toCamelCase(java.lang.String,boolean,char...)